# Chrome - text not staying within its element border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, webkit

So I have a JS function which will display a url under a file preview container after it is uploaded to the server. On firefox, if the text is too long to fit under the preview container above it, it will wrap to the next line which is what I want. On Chromium however, it just extends out as long as it needs to, and will overlap with other things. 
How can I fix this? Is there some webkit specific thing I need to set? I tried setting a text-wrap but it had no effect.

```
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
        var span = document.createElement('span'); 
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = responseText;
        a.innerHTML = responseText;
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        a.setAttribute('link', 'color:#000000');
        span.appendChild(a);
        span.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; 
            webkit-box-sizing: border-box; bottom: -28px; left: 3px; right: 3px;  
            height: 28px; line-height: 28px; text-color: #000000; "); 

        file.previewTemplate.appendChild(span);

        });
}
```

Firefox: 
[image: ff]

Chromium:
[image]

EDIT: I'm using dropzone.js, the parent element is a preview container, styled like this:

```
.dropzone .dz-preview,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 17px;
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px solid #acacac;
 padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
 width:100px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: `webkit` !== `-webkit`.

Comment: Also, don't forget: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: Switched it to -webkit-box-sizing, still getting the same result.

Comment: Actually the answer depends on the CSS of the first positioned parent element of `span`.

Comment: edited, parent element is a preview container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: Fixed by adding the `word-wrap: break-word;` property in the setAttribute. 
Looks fine in Firefox too.